# Final temperature of a adiabatic process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> One molar of a perfect gas of $C_v = \pu{20.18 J/K}$ at $\pu{3.25atm}$ and $\pu{310 K}$ undergoes adiabatic expansion to reach a final state of $\pu{2.50atm}$. Calculate final volume and temperature.

---

Since $PV^{\gamma} = const$ and $\displaystyle T^{C_v/R}V = const$,

$$V_f = V_i\left(P_i\over P_f \right)^{1\over \gamma}$$

Which I got as [$\pu{0.0113m^3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.00782%20*%20(1.3)%5E((%20(20.8%20%2B%208.314)%2F20.8)%20)) and [$V_i = \pu{0.00782 m^3}$](http://8.314%20*%20310%20/(3.25%20*%201.013*%2010%5E5)) .

To get final temperature I used 
[$$T_f = T_i\left(V_i\over V_f \right)^{R\over C_v} = 310\left(0.00782\over 0.0113 \right)^{8.314\over 20.8} = \pu{267K}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=310(0.00782%2F%200.0113%20)%5E(8.314%2F20.8))

But when I use equation of state to get final temperature I get [$\pu{344K}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.50*1.013*10%5E5*0.0113%2F8.314) which is the correct answer.

Why did not equation of state and $\displaystyle T^{C_v/R}V= const$ match in this case ?

Comment: How are you obtaining Gamma? Your equation for the volume and temperature also doesn't look right. Where are you getting $\frac {\text{C}_v}{\mathrm{R}}$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process

Comment: @Tyberius Gamma is $C_p/C_v$ ? and $C_p - C_v = nR $ no ?

Comment: @Tyberius Sorry I forgot to include the initial temperature if that is what you asked.

Comment: From your equation, I don't get 0.0113 for the final volume.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I have linked the calculations. Can you tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: You raised it to the $\gamma$ instead of $1/\gamma$

Comment: I see now how you are getting (Cv/R). How I notice now that the answer you say is correct can't possibly be correct, as the temperature will always go down in an adiabatic expansion.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Still I get $V_f= 0.0094$ and $T_f = 288.016$ which is still very far ?

Comment: @Tyberius But I used equation of states to get that answer and it is also given in the book. what have I missed ?

Comment: With that new value for $V_f$, the equation of state should also give $T_f=288K$. The textbook has to be wrong, because an increase in temperature *cannot* happen for an adiabatic expansion.

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you, if you don't mind can you write an answer ?

Comment: 288 is correct.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes thanks.  Can you write an answer ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  You already did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error stems from a miscalculation of $\mathrm{V_f}$ in the first calculation. As mentioned in the comments, it appears that you actually exponentiated by $\gamma$ rather than $\frac 1 \gamma$. When you differentiate by $\frac 1 \gamma$ , you should obtain $\mathrm{V_f}=0.0094 \mathrm{m^3}$.

Plugging this into your expression for $\mathrm{T_f}$, you should obtain:$$T_f = T_i\left(V_i\over V_f \right)^{R\over C_v} = 310\left(0.00782\over 0.0094 \right)^{8.314\over 20.8} = 288\mathrm{K}$$

Similarly, inserting this into the ideal gas equation, you should obtain: $$\mathrm{T_f= {P_fV_f \over R}}={(2.5)(0.0094) \over(8.206\times10^{-5})}=288\mathrm{K}$$ (The ideal equation will be slightly off as written due to rounding).

In regards to the textbook solution, the final temperature could not possibly be higher than the initial. An adiabatic expansion always reduces the temperature. Intuitively, we can understand this by noting that an expansion with no heat exchange should decrease the internal energy and thus decrease the temperature of the system.

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you check http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71629/change-in-internal-not-zero-for-an-isothermal-process ?